# Array writes all into one column in CSV, PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, fputcsv

```
function writePlayerInfo($playerFName, $phone, $email, $position){
    $handleName = fopen("data/playerInfo.csv","a");
    $id = newID('data/playerInfo.csv');
    $data = array();
    array_push($data, $id, $playerFName, $phone, $email, $position);
    fputcsv($handleName, $data, "\t");
    fclose($handleName);
    $datas = array();
```

Hi guys,

I have an empty array that i push some data into and then write to a CSV., I want each value of the array top be written in a different column, example:

```
col1 |  col2 |  col4 |  col5 |  col6

id   |  name | phone | email |  positon
```

Currently my code does the following:

```
col1 | 

id  name  phone  email   positon
```

My current code is stopping me extracting specific data

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Comment: You used fputcsv with tab as separator so maybe values are in different columns but you didn't see it because tab is a whitespace character...?

Comment: What was i thinking... i simply implemented a white space when you need a comma to define next column.